# whatapps open window

Tags: ios, whatsapp

I need to know if you can open a contact from whatapps with "abid=+2827272727" command.

```
NSURL *whatsappURL = [NSURL
URLWithString:@"whatsapp://send?abid=+2827272727&amp;text=Hola!"];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:whatsappURL]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:whatsappURL];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, but be aware that abid is not the Contacts Phone Number.
It is [ABRecordGetRecordID](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABRecordRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/ABRecordGetRecordID)

Try this code to open whatsapp with the contact named "Your Name" in your address book.

```
    // Fetch the address book
    ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL,NULL);
    dispatch_semaphore_t sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
    ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBook, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error) {
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);
    });
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

    // find user
    CFStringRef searchQuery = CFSTR("Your Contact Name");

    CFArrayRef array = ABAddressBookCopyPeopleWithName (addressBook,searchQuery);
    int items = CFArrayGetCount(array);
    NSLog(@"found %i persons",items);

    int abid = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < items; i++)
    {
        ABRecordRef person = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(array, i);
        abid = ABRecordGetRecordID(person);
        NSLog(@"found person %i ",abid);
        break;
    }

    if (abid > 0)
    {
        NSString* url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"whatsapp://send?abid=%i&text=Hola",abid];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    }
```